# How do I scan a sentence into an array of strings?

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

I have a text file where two types of format occur. After scanning through the first format type and putting it into an array, the second format is encountered:
    `$$$$$$$`
    `I have a big tree full of money`

How do I ignore the line of $$$$$$$ and scan the sentence into a new array where each element is a word in the sentence:

```
`char sentence[MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH]`
```

I have tried to use:

```
for (i = 0; i < MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH; i++){
        if (scanf(" $$$$$$$ %s", sentence[i]) !=1){
                break;
```

But this doesn't account for the fact that the `$$$$$$$` only occurs once before the sentence. It also returns a formatting warning:
`format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You mind creating a [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Thank you! Which part would you like an example of?

Comment: The line `$$$$$$` is used in the input file to show that the next line will contain a sentence to be scanned into an array of words. In this array, each word is a word in the sentence (stored in the order of appearance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue in your program is that you expect to read in an array of strings, but your data structure is a single string. Your compiler should actually have warned you.
Then, scan the first element with `" $$$$$$$ %s"` format, the following ones with `"%s"` only:

```
const int MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH = 30;
const int MAX_NR_OF_SENTENCES = 30;

char sentence[MAX_NR_OF_SENTENCES][MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH];

int i=0;
if (scanf(" $$$$$$$ %29s", sentence[i]) == 1) {
    i++;
    while (i < MAX_NR_OF_SENTENCES) {
        if (scanf("%29s", sentence[i]) !=1){
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```